# id that looks like footnote causing "Definition not found" in org-export

Tags: org-export

When exporting an org-mode file to html, when UUID contain the string "fb", error `org-export--missing-definitions: Definition not found for footnote 1` would be reported, aborting the export, if there is no footnote subtree.

and the label would change, "fb" would be footnote 1, "fe" would be footnote 2. also "3ae7902e-13a9-439b-8a9b-dd76cea10196" cause footnote 2 missing, so it may be an org-id thing?

To illustrate, this file is problematic, and will give the above error.

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ID: 7e8052c5-8cfb-4131-b456-220719060b5a
:END:
#+title: atomic
#+filetags: :draft:
property of being self-contained; not dependent on others/upstream.
* [[id:673610ee-8ba5-4918-80a4-80f800df9dfe][zettelkasten]]
notes being atomic means that the note would manage to address an idea with as little reference as possible, and as much literal and plain words as possible
```

but nor will this one (org-footnote-new)

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ID: 7e8052c5-8cfb-4131-b456-220719060b5a
:END:
#+title: atomic
#+filetags: :draft:

property of being self-contained; not dependent on others/upstream.[fn:1]
* [[id:673610ee-8ba5-4918-80a4-80f800df9dfe][zettelkasten]]
notes being atomic means that the note would manage to address an idea with as little reference as possible, and as much literal and plain words as possible

* Footnotes

[fn:1]
```

or this one (deleteing "b" in the "8cfb" section in ID)

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ID: 7e8052c5-8cf-4131-b456-220719060b5a
:END:
#+title: atomic
#+filetags: :draft:
property of being self-contained; not dependent on others/upstream.
* [[id:673610ee-8ba5-4918-80a4-80f800df9dfe][zettelkasten]]
notes being atomic means that the note would manage to address an idea with as little reference as possible, and as much literal and plain words as possible
```

A temporary fix is attaching footnote in every such file or with a hook, but does anyone know how this would happen and/or how to fix this?

edit:
My org-mode version

```
Org mode version 9.7 (9.7-??-57b94f3 @ /home/linfeng/emacs-distros/doomemacs/.local/straight/build-29.1/org/)
```

as NickD pointed out, `emacs -Q` with the file then org-export do not have the footnote issue

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: I created a referent for the `zettelkasten` link (I had to add its ID to the ID database with `org-id-add-location`), but after that exporting the file succeeded with no problem. What version of Org mode are you running? `M-x org-version` will tell you. Please add that info to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After probing around my configuration, I was able to locate the problem: I have a `publish.el` script which includes

```
(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-functions 'collect-backlinks-string)
```

In `collect-backlinks-string`, paragraphs in other files with link to this org-id would be copied and pasted in a subtree, and some of them have footnotes in it, causing arbitary `footnote n missing` error.

Changing org-id make the issue disappears as it'd prevent any text to be copied in `collect-backlinks-string`.

I fixed the problem by adding this line

```
(let* (...
       (text ... ;; getting text
       (text (s-replace-regexp "\\[fn:[0-9]+\\]" "" text)) ;; this line
       ...)
)
```

after where text of reference is retrieved.

Many thanks to NickD's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug to me. Can you use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to send all of that information to the developers mailing list?

Comment: I think the OP should first make sure that it is a bug, rather than a config problem. Starting it with `emacs -Q` and a minimal init file (if necessary) is probably the first step.